# Exporting a box with a hole

Tags: export, obj

I'm trying to build a scene in p5.js where a ball falls through a circular hole in a wall. I used Blender to generate a wall (a thin box) with a hole in it by applying a difference modifier to a box and a cylinder. When I load the file to the browser (e.g. using [this site](https://3dviewer.net/#), or using p5.js loadModel command), I get a wall with no hole, or with a weird mesh inside the hole instead. This is my first experience with Blender, so I'm sorry if this is an obvious mistake.

Here is the blender file: [image]

Many thanks,

-Matan

Comment: You can upload a Blend file here: https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions on that page to insert the link into your question. I assume you deleted the cylinder before exporting the file?

Comment: Thanks @JohnEason! I haven't deleted the cylinder because when I did the hole disappeared. To make sure it worked I exported the object and then loaded it into a different blender project. It seemed okay because only one object loaded, with a hole in it. But I guess this is where the issue is?

Comment: Apply the modifier and delete the cutter. Or, better still, model the hole withoout using a Boolean.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to apply the modifier within Blender. (Note that although you've phrased what you've done as, "applying a difference modifier", in Blender "applying a modifier" is different than an object having a modifier. Currently your object just has the modifier) Use CTRL + A with your cursor over the modifier in the modifier stack.

Alternatively, when you use File->Export, looking through the settings on the right for ones that relate to modifiers. There should be a checkbox that controls whether the modifiers are applied upon export. Ensure that it is enabled.

Comment: Thanks! I followed these steps (I applied the modifier. the 'apply modifiers' option was already checked), but the object is still strange when loaded to the browser (https://blend-exchange.com/b/6p4qGXnD/)

Comment: (it's not that the modifier is not applied at all, I do get a circle in the center of the box, it's just not a hole)

Comment: Ah, I see now. I believe that the issue stems from the fact that the resulting object has concave n-gons. One simple solution would be to triangulate the mesh. You may either use the Triangulate Face operator in Edit Mode or use the triangulate modifier.

Comment: It worked! Thanks! :)